# How to detect client use network ipv6 or ipv4 in PHP

Tags: php

I want use code php to check client use ipv6 or ipv4 network. But this function only return ipv4 address.

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Please help me to detect client use ipv6! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if someone connected via IPv6 / IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448871/how-to-check-if-someone-connected-via-ipv6-ipv4) <- I would recommend looking at "Mukesh Chapagain"'s-answer.

Comment: There's also loads of other hits on this topic if you simply had googled on your title (which you _always_ should do before posting a question).

Answer (score -1):

```
echo  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

if you get ipv4 than client uses ipv4 else ipv6

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: That's just for _getting_ the IP (which the OP already does better than this example). The question is how to detect if the IP they're getting is an IPv4 or IPv6-address.